# iOS push notifications for distribution

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification, provisioning

I have been developing an iOS app that uses push notifications. This is my first time using push notifications, so I followed this tutorial: [raywenderlich push-notification](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1)  I followed this exactly several times, it worked perfectly for a development provisioning profile. Now the app is ready for submission. I created a distribution provisioning profile in the same way as I did the development. on the php side I modified the following line of code to remove the sandbox:

```
$fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);
```

in xcode I changed the apps build configuration to release and built and run on my device. However the device is not receiving the notifications. I am not sure what is the cause of this? I also am not sure how to find out what is wrong. If anyone can help me resolve this issue I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an updated device token on the server side since running the release build on your device? Sandbox and production apps generate *different* device tokens, so you'll need to make sure you're using the correct one when trying to send a push.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I did use the latest device token. So that must not be my problem